# Good practices for pulling from git repo into production server

Tags: linux, laravel, git, ubuntu

I have a DigitalOcean VPS with ubuntu and a few laravel projects, for my projects initial setup I do a git clone to create a folder with my application files from my online repository.

I do all development work in my local machine, where I have two branches (master and develop), what I do is merge develop into my local master, then I push from master into my local repository.

Nw back into my production server, when I want to add all the changes added into production I do a git pull from origin, so far this has resulted into git telling me to stash my changes, why is this?

What would be the best approach to pull changes into production server? take in mind that my production server has no working directory perse, all I do in my VPS is either clone or push upgrades into production.

Comment: I would recommend not cloning or pulling from a production server at all. There are better ways to deploy

Answer (score 3):

You can take a look at the CI/CD (continuous integration / continuous delivery) systems. [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines.html) for example offer free-to-use plan for small teams.

You can create a pipeline with a manual deploy step (you have to press a button after the code is merged to the master branch) and use whatever tool you like to deploy your code (scp, rsync, ftp, sftp etc.).

And the biggest benefit is that you can have multiple intermediate steps (even for the working branches) where you can run unit tests which would prevent you to upload failing builds (whenever you merge non-working code)

Answer (score 2):

For the first problem, do a `git status` on production to see which files that git sees as changed or added and consider adding them to your `.gitignore` file (which itself should be a part of your repo). Laravel generally has good defaults for these, but you might have added things or deviated from them in the process of upgrading Laravel.

For the deployment, the best practice is to have something that is consistent, reproducible, loggable, and revertable. For this, I would recommend choosing a deployment utility. These usually do pretty much the same thing:

1. You define deployment parameters in code, which you can commit as a part of your repo (not passwords, of course, but things like the server name, deploy path, and deploy tasks).
2. You initiate a deploy directly from your local computer.
3. The script/utility SSH's into your target server and pulls the latest code from the remote git repo (authorized via SSH key forwarded into the server) into a 'release' folder.
4. The script does any additional tasks you define (`composer install`, `npm run prod`, `systemctl restart php-fpm`, soft-linking shared files like `.env`, and etc.)
5. The script soft-links the document root to your new 'release' folder, which results in an essentially zero-downtime deployment. If any of the previous steps fail, or you find a bug in the latest release, you just soft-link to the previous release folder and your site still works.

Here are some solutions you can check out that all do this sort of thing:

- [Laravel Envoyer](https://envoyer.io/): A 1st-party (paid) service that allows you to deploy via a web-based GUI.
- [Laravel Envoy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/envoy): A 1st-party (free) package that allows you to connect to your prod server and script deployment tasks. It's very bare-bones in that you have to write all of the commands yourself, but some may prefer that.
- [Capistrano](https://capistranorb.com/): This is (free) a tried-and-tested popular ruby-based deployment utility.
- [Deployer](https://deployer.org/): The (free) PHP equivalent of Capistrano. Easier to use, has a lot of built-in tasks (including a Laravel one), and doesn't require ruby.

Using these utilities is not necessarily exclusive of doing CI/CD if you want to go that route. You can use these tools to define the CD step in your pipeline while still doing other steps beforehand.